# How to pass a multidimensional array by reference when it has dynamic bounds?

Tags: c++

I have an int array myArray[x][y] and I wish to pass this to a function by reference, but it seems like it either needs constant bounds or some odd pointer workaround? How do I do this properly?

Comment: I already looked there and it did not seem to compile when I tried the variants included there, this is a much simpler case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array with automatic storage duration always requires compile-time constant bounds. The fact that you can do `int array[x];` where `x` is not a compile-time constant in GCC is merely a non-portable extension. Indeed, you cannot pass such a non-standard array by reference to a function.

You could just pass the bounds along with the array, but you're much better off using a standard container such as `std::vector`.

Comment: but since it is multidimensional wouldn't it be a vector of vectors?

Comment: @user1947180 Yes, it would be: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(x, std::vector<int>(y));`

Comment: Does that initialize them to 0 by default?

Comment: Or, if you want/need to have the array as a single memory block, use a single vector and index it like `v[x + rowLength*y]`.

Comment: @user1947180 Yes, it will.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
template<int X, int Y>
void ArrayFn( int (&in)[X][Y] )
{
    in[X-1][Y-1] = 666; // or whatever
}
```

And call it like:

```
int arr[3][3];
ArrayFn( arr );
```